# Error shutting down JBoss from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss5.x

I get an exception when I shutdown JBoss server from within Eclipse.
I run JBoss IDE 1.5.105 and Eclipse 3.3.2
How do I solve this problem?

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jboss/system/server/ServerImplMBean
>     at
>   org.jboss.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:118)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.system.server.ServerImplMBean
>     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
>     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
>     ... 1 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just downloaded and reinstalled the jboss server.
Never got that error again.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-1226), check how the shutdown is called and if `client/jbossall-client.jar` is part of the `$JBOSSCP` (jboss classpath) for the shutdown command.

```
#define the classpath for the shutdown class
#JBOSSCP=${JBOSSCP:-"$JBOSS_HOME/bin/shutdown.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/client/jnet.jar"}
JBOSSCP=${JBOSSCP:-"$BINARY_HOME/client/jbossall-client.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/bin/shutdown.jar"}
```